# How to label time series data for CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to classify time series data using a CNN (given model).
My input signal data is given as shape = (nr. channels x samples x nr. trials) where:

- nr. channels = number of sensors recording simultaneously
- samples = split my signal into 3s windows so the training data will have the same length 3s x sample rate
- nr. trials = by splitting the signal into windows, I obtain X chunks

The time series/signal data is subject based, for each subject I have numerous signals recorded. The labels are also subject based and not signal based (so it's not an event classification problem, but more of a global subject classification one), meaning that for each subject's recording I will have the same label. Example:

SUBJECT 1 -> 12 recorded signals of about 2 min each -> split into 3s windows -> all of which will have the same label

So I have an excel table where for each subject I have an associated class. I have extracted these labels and I've tried shaping them as (1 x samples x nr. trials).

The model I'm using requires the NHWC (trials, channels, samples, kernels) format so I have reshaped my training data as:

```
X train shape = (2642, 14, 384, 1)
y train shape = (2642, 1, 384, 1)
```

But I get a

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
   x sizes: 14
   y sizes: 1
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
```

How would I need to shape my labels data? Reshape it as (2642, 14, 384, 1) making it the same shape as the training data? Or?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it by trying different things.
The labels, y_train, array had to be shaped as

```
(trials, 1)
```

where trials in my case was the number of windows generated by windowing the signal